# adjacency matrix sum of corresponding rows and columns

Tags: c

What is the easiest way to sum the rows and columns, of the same index, on an adjacency matrix?

Here is one example:

```
      A  B  C  D
    A 1  0  2  1
    B 3  -  -  -
    C 0  -  -  -
    D 1  -  -  -
```

where the (-) are entries. How can I sum the A column with A row, B column with B row....

example, for A: (1 + 0 + 2 + 1) + (1 + 3 + 0 + 1) = 9

Comment: stack overflow is no "do my homework" service!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this code ....i have added comment in the code to understand the logic

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main(){

    int arr[20][20],i,j,n;
    int k,sum=0;

    printf("\nEnter matrix size: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);



    printf("\nEnter the matrix");

    // to read the matrix 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
      }
    }


     //to display the matrix 
     printf("\nMatrix is : ");
     for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       printf("\n");
       for(j=0;j<n;j++){
          printf(" %d",arr[i][j]);
       }
     }


      k=0;

      //to add corresponding rows and column elements 

      while(k<n){

       sum=0;   
       for(i=0;i<n;i++){
         sum=sum+arr[k][i]; 
       }

       for(i=0;i<n;i++){
         sum=sum+arr[i][k]; 
       }

       //to print the result 
       printf("\nFor row and column number %d  sum is %d",k,sum);

       k++;

      }
}
```

Comment: stack overflow is no "do my homework" service!

Comment: yes i know this is not a "do my homework " service. i thought he/she has a problem and stuck with that ..that's why i helped :).....nothing wrong in that

Comment: You should have asked for a [mcve] and tell [ask]. OP should have at least  to show her code. So, yes, there is something wrong with that. Don't pros**te just for some reps!

Comment: yes thanks i will remember this for my next posts ...... :)